# Adding empty record for nested attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, has-many

I'm working in Rails 4/Ruby 2.0.0. I have a two models - `Articles` and `Graphics`. `Articles` `has_many` `Graphics`. So, in my code I am trying to add an empty record to the graphics collection on the article so that in the form, there will be an empty set of fields to let a new record be added. I cannot figure out why the fields do not show up on the form though.

I've tried multiple methods of building the graphics collection but none seem to do the trick. Surely I must be missing something insanely small.

#### Article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :graphics, :dependent => :destroy, :foreign_key => 'article_id' 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :graphics,
      :allow_destroy => true,
      :reject_if     => :all_blank
end
```

#### Graphic.rb

```
class Graphic < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    validates_presence_of :path, :caption
end
```

#### _form.html.erb

```
...
<% f.fields_for :graphics do |g| %>
    <div class="clear clearfix pad-b-20">
        <div class="w-1-2 left f-left">
          <div class="field">
            <%= g.label :path %><br>
            <%= g.text_field :path %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w-1-2 left f-left">
          <div class="field">
            <%= g.label :caption %><br>
            <%= g.text_field :caption %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
...
```

### Building it in a form helper method

#### articles/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(setup_article(@article)) do |f| %>
```

#### form_helper.rb

```
module FormHelper
    def setup_article(article)
        article.graphics.build
        article
    end  
end
```

### Using an ActiveRecord callback

#### Article.rb

```
...
after_initialize :build_graphics

private

def build_graphics
    self.graphics.build
end
```

### Building it in the controller

#### ArticleController.rb

```
...
def new
    @article = Article.new
    @article.graphics.build
end
...
```

Comment: doing it in the controller is the default way of doing it. the rest looks good. are you maybe using strong parameters? i would recommend reading this http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/ and watching this http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the strong parameters, I did forget to add it to the permitted list so I'm sure that would've cause be problems down the road. But unfortunately that didn't fix the problem. I'll look in to those links now and see if that reveals anything.

Comment: I think you're missing an ```=``` sign: ```<%= f.fields_for :graphics```

Comment: @Alex , the missing `=` was exactly the problem. I hate problems like that, I stared at it for hours glazing over that. It doesn't help I've never been clear on when to use one and when not to. What is the norm for showing a comment solved my problem since I don't have an answer to mark?

Comment: I will add an answer for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both for `form_for` and for `fields_for` you need to use `<%=`, because they render the contents of the form.

So, to solve your problem, you need to write

```
...
<%= f.fields_for :graphics do |g| %>
   Your content
<% end %>
...
```